# Remove word 'sip:' from dialing number

Tags: html, sip, voip

I use a softphone called eyebeam. When I click on a sip link like:

```
    <a href="sip:0123456789">0123456789</a>
```

It will start eyeBeam and directly call the number. Now the problem is that it adds the word "sip:" infront of the number so eyeBeam doesn't recognize it.

My question is how can I only call the number and ignore the word "sip:" ?

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: Well it's just a link that triggers the windows sip protocol that starts my eyeBeam. It will execute this command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CounterPath\eyeBeam 1.5\eyeBeam.exe" "-dial=%1" . Where dial is the command and %1 is everything in the href.

Comment: but how does it get the value from href? Can't you do a javascript replace("sip:", "") ?

Comment: I've tried onclick change href without sip but than it becomes a normal link and the browser redirects me to it.

Comment: `<a href="sip:0123456789@0123456789">0123456789</a>` this will also work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem wasn't the word sip but it was because some telephone number contained 
"-", "()" and spaces. So eyeBeam didn't recognize the number.

Comment: In my case, the number has not contained any special characters, it is just a plain number, but still getting same issue that you faced. can you please share your code for reference?